# Disabling WSDL file validation in Zend Studio

Tags: php, validation, wsdl, zend-studio

How can I disable WSDL file validation in Zend Studio? I have many WSDL files in a project and it takes much much time to validate all of them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Zend Studio. But since it's based on Eclipse, i guess you can disable validation by going to Project Settings->Validation Tab, and deselect the WSDL validator.